# Set up CDN with Cloudflare

Tags: performance, hosting, cdn

I'm trying to reduce the number of request, so I take a look only and these are the solution to move the media folder:

- Use a file server
- Use a CDN
  I have no clue on how to achive the first method and I doubt I can even use it on a shared server, so I have unseccessfuly adopted the second one.
  I don't understand how CDN works, but I have tried to set up one to store the media folder 
  Server structure:

  mysite.com
    public_html
      shop -> magento folder
        media

What I have done:

- Created a subdomain called: media.mysite.com with root in public_html/shop/media
- CNAMED it to mysite.com
- Activated Cloudflare,result:

  ```
  CNAME   media.farmaciacaloini.com   points to media.farmaciacaloini.com.cdn.cloudflare.net
  ```
- Magento->Admin->System->Web->Non Secure

  ```
  Base Media 
  URL=http://media.farmaciacaloini.com.cdn.cloudflare.net/media/
  ```

Unfortunately I can't see any image ony frontpage

Comment: here is a decent cdn module that should do most of what you want (minus the cloudflare), either way its a good start: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/onepica-imagecdn-1.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a problem of my hosting service: Hostgator, the integrated panel function doesn't work, you have to follow the manual instruction on cloudflare and disable the function of cpanel

Answer (score 3):

Here is a module that allows you to use cloud flare with magento:

it's called: Control for CloudFlare

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/control-for-cloudflarer.html

Here is a module for CDN, its called: OnePica ImageCDN

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/onepica-imagecdn-1.html